# When does stock options start expiring on Monday and Wednesday?

Tags: united-states, options, expiration

I recall that traditional options expire on the 3rd Friday of the month and that weekly options expire every  Friday.

I was looking at [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/options?p=SPY)
and I saw some options that expire on  Oct 28, 2019 (Monday) and Oct 30, 2019 (Wednesday).

Where I can find confirmation of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the CBOE](http://www.cboe.com/products/stock-index-options-spx-rut-msci-ftse/s-p-500-index-options/spx-weeklys-options-spxw):

> In 2016 Cboe began to offer SPXW Weeklys with Monday and Wednesday expirations, in addition to the existing SPXW Weeklys with Friday expirations (SPXW EOW).

Comment: It appears now some options are expiring in morning also, Is that true ?

Comment: Yes, there are options that expire in the morning. Particularly vexing are index options that expire the previous day and settlement price is  based on the opening stock prices for each stock in the index the next morning.